# Unable to add user

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to add user to CouchDB (3.1.0) installed on MacOS 10.15.5:

```
curl -u admin:<pass> -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:eiri -d '{"name": "test", "password": "test", "roles": [], "type": "user"}'
```

However I always get

```
{
  "error": "unknown_error",
  "reason": "undefined"
}
```

The logs don't tell me much either

> -------- rexi_server: from: couchdb@127.0.0.1(<0.4835.0>) mfa: fabric_rpc:update_docs/3 exit:{timeout,{gen_server,call,[couch_proc_manager,{get_proc,{doc,<<"_design/_auth">>,{1,[<<117,58,224,21,122,139,26,34,51,159,60,14,244,241,191,25>>]},{[{<<"language">>,<<"javascript">>},{<<"validate_doc_update">>,<<"\n    function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj) {\n        if (newDoc._deleted === true) {\n            // allow deletes by admins and matching users\n            // without checking the other fields\n            if ((userCtx.roles.indexOf('_admin') !== -1) ||\n                (userCtx.name == oldDoc.name)) {\n                return;\n            } else {\n                throw({forbidden: 'Only admins may delete other user docs.'});\n            }\n        }\n\n        if (newDoc.type !== 'user') {\n            throw({forbidden : 'doc.type must be user'});\n        } // we only allow user docs for now\n\n        if (!newDoc.name) {\n            throw({forbidden: 'doc.name is required'});\n        }\n\n        if (!newDoc.roles) {\n            throw({forbidden: 'doc.roles must exist'});\n        }\n\n        if (!isArray(newDoc.roles)) {\n            throw({forbidden: 'doc.roles must be an array'});\n        }\n\n        for (var idx = 0; idx < newDoc.roles.length; idx++) {\n            if (typeof newDoc.roles[idx] !== 'string') {\n                throw({forbidden: 'doc.roles can only contain strings'});\n            }\n        }\n\n        if (newDoc._id !== ('org.couchdb.user:' + newDoc.name)) {\n            throw({\n                forbidden: 'Doc ID must be of the form org.couchdb.user:name'\n            });\n        }\n\n        if (oldDoc) { // validate all updates\n            if (oldDoc.name !== newDoc.name) {\n                throw({forbidden: 'Usernames can not be changed.'});\n            }\n        }\n\n        if (newDoc.password_sha && !newDoc.salt) {\n            throw({\n                forbidden: 'Users with password_sha must have a salt.' +\n                    'See /_utils/script/couch.js for example code.'\n            });\n        }\n\n        var available_schemes = ["simple", "pbkdf2", "bcrypt"];\n        if (newDoc.password_scheme\n                && available_schemes.indexOf(newDoc.password_scheme) == -1) {\n            throw({\n                forbidden: 'Password scheme `' + newDoc.password_scheme\n                    + '` not supported.'\n            });\n        }\n\n        if (newDoc.password_scheme === "pbkdf2") {\n            if (typeof(newDoc.iterations) !== "number") {\n               throw({forbidden: "iterations must be a number."});\n            }\n            if (typeof(newDoc.derived_key) !== "string") {\n               throw({forbidden: "derived_key must be a string."});\n            }\n        }\n\n        var is_server_or_database_admin = function(userCtx, secObj) {\n            // see if the user is a server admin\n            if(userCtx.roles.indexOf('_admin') !== -1) {\n                return true; // a server admin\n            }\n\n            // see if the user a database admin specified by name\n            if(secObj && secObj.admins && secObj.admins.names) {\n                if(secObj.admins.names.indexOf(userCtx.name) !== -1) {\n                    return true; // database admin\n                }\n            }\n\n            // see if the user a database admin specified by role\n            if(secObj && secObj.admins && secObj.admins.roles) {\n                var db_roles = secObj.admins.roles;\n                for(var idx = 0; idx < userCtx.roles.length; idx++) {\n                    var user_role = userCtx.roles[idx];\n                    if(db_roles.indexOf(user_role) !== -1) {\n                        return true; // role matches!\n                    }\n                }\n            }\n\n            return false; // default to no admin\n        }\n\n        if (!is_server_or_database_admin(userCtx, secObj)) {\n            if (oldDoc) { // validate non-admin updates\n                if (userCtx.name !== newDoc.name) {\n                    throw({\n                        forbidden: 'You may only update your own user document.'\n                    });\n                }\n                // validate role updates\n                var oldRoles = (oldDoc.roles || []).sort();\n                var newRoles = newDoc.roles.sort();\n\n                if (oldRoles.length !== newRoles.length) {\n                    throw({forbidden: 'Only _admin may edit roles'});\n                }\n\n                for (var i = 0; i < oldRoles.length; i++) {\n                    if (oldRoles[i] !== newRoles[i]) {\n                        throw({forbidden: 'Only _admin may edit roles'});\n                    }\n                }\n            } else if (newDoc.roles.length > 0) {\n                throw({forbidden: 'Only *admin may set roles'});\n            }\n        }\n\n        // no system roles in users db\n        for (var i = 0; i < newDoc.roles.length; i++) {\n            if (newDoc.roles[i] !== '*metrics') {\n              if (newDoc.roles[i][0] === '*') {\n                  throw({\n                      forbidden:\n                      'No system roles (starting with underscore) in users db.'\n                  });\n              }\n            }\n        }\n\n        // no system names as names\n        if (newDoc.name[0] === '*') {\n            throw({forbidden: 'Username may not start with underscore.'});\n        }\n\n        var badUserNameChars = [':'];\n\n        for (var i = 0; i < badUserNameChars.length; i++) {\n            if (newDoc.name.indexOf(badUserNameChars[i]) >= 0) {\n                throw({forbidden: 'Character `' + badUserNameChars[i] +\n                        '` is not allowed in usernames.'});\n            }\n        }\n    }\n">>}]},[],false,[]},{<<"_design/_auth">>,<<"1-753ae0157a8b1a22339f3c0ef4f1bf19">>}},5000]}} [{gen_server,call,3,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,223}]},{couch_query_servers,get_ddoc_process,2,[{file,"src/couch_query_servers.erl"},{line,614}]},{couch_query_servers,with_ddoc_proc,2,[{file,"src/couch_query_servers.erl"},{line,513}]},{couch_query_servers,validate_doc_update,5,[{file,"src/couch_query_servers.erl"},{line,368}]},{couch_db,'-validate_doc_update_int/3-lc$^0/1-0-',5,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,903}]},{couch_db,'-validate_doc_update_int/3-fun-1-',3,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,906}]},{couch_stats,update_histogram,2,[{file,"src/couch_stats.erl"},{line,102}]},{couch_db,'-prep_and_validate_updates/6-fun-1-',3,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,1003}]}]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're specifying `org.couchdb.user:eiri` but the JSON body specifies `"name": "test"`. The names have to match.  Try `"name: eiri"`.  Adding `-H "Accept: application/json"` and 
     `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` wouldn't hurt either, https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html#creating-a-new-user

Comment: thanks @RamblinRose but .... I changed to `org.couchdb.user:test`, `Content-Type: application/json`, `Accept: application/json` and tried with other REST Client but this doesn't seem to work either and I still have `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: Sounds like bigger problems, good luck